# Using Ember.js, how do I display HTML in fixture data with Helpers and SafeString?

Tags: ember.js

Easily I can accomplish the task by wrapping handlebar expressions in three curly braces, e.g., {{{html}}}, but Ember.js recommends we first escape any user data.

The following fixture has the HTML that I want to appear (Hello, I'm HTML!).

```
var posts = [{
    category: 'Code',
    id: 'cssbestpractices',
    title: 'CSS Best Practices',
    date: { weekday: 'Friday', month: 'November', day: '1', year: '2013' },
    html: '<li>Hello, I am HTML!</li>'
}...
```

The expression.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post">
 {{highlight html}}
</script>
```

And the Helper I'm attempting to add...

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('highlight', function(value, options) {
  var html = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(value);
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(html);
});
```

How would I go about passing HTML trough the Handlebars SafeString method? Here is where I am at in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/PjPaP/). Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get rid of the `escapeExpression`, make sure this is your data though, this opens dangerous doors.

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('rawhtml', function(value, options) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(value);
});

{{rawhtml html}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can now use many expressions and only have to maintain one Helper. Clever! Thanks again!